# confusion when to use viewsets.Viewset and viewsets.ModelViewSet in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

According to django rest frame work 3.7 `(viewsets.ViewSet)` will provide routes for a standard set of create/retrieve/update/destroy style actions

and

`(viewsets.ModelViewSet)` also will provide routes for a standard set of create/retrieve/update/destroy style actions

so when to use this two class and what is the difference between this two. and get_objects() method can we override in `(viewsets.ViewSet)` class? or  get_objects() method  only limited to `(viewsets.ModelViewSet)` class?.Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe somebody else will give a more complete answer, but here's the quick and dirty.  A ModelViewset is a Viewset that is very easy to configure for CRUD operations on your data model.  If you are looking to expose a REST API for an object defined in your models.py, the quickest way to expose that is with a ModelViewSet.  A viewset is much more wide open with respect to application.  You could build a model CRUD endpoint with a Viewset, but you could also build an endpoint that doesn't tie into the model at all.  You have a lot of flexibility with a ViewSet, but a ModelViewset is more constrained, but requires less configuration to accomplish most model based tasks.

Answer (score 5):

i need to add some more details. i am using doc code explain further

1. **viewsets.ViewSet**

   ```
   class ViewSet(ViewSetMixin, views.APIView):
        """
        The base ViewSet class does not provide any actions by default.
        """
        pass
   ```

this means `ViewSet` inherited two class `ViewSetMixin`(it gives just binding the 'GET' and 'POST' methods to the 'list' and 'create' actions) and `views.APIView`(this gives authentication_classes, permission_classes, etc... attributes ). so `viewsets.ViewSet` does not provide any concrete actions methods by default but you have to manualy override list,create,update, etc... methods.

2. **viewsets.ModelViewSet**

```
class ModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                        mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                        mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                        mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        GenericViewSet):
         """
         A viewset that provides default create(),retrieve(),update(),
         partial_update(), destroy() and list() actions.
         """
         pass
```

this means **ModelViewSet** inherited **all most all mixins** so it provides default list,create,update etc.. action methods and **GenericViewSet** ( it provides the `get_object` and `get_queryset` methods, You'll need to either set these attributes, or override `get_queryset()`/`get_serializer_class()` because `GenericViewSet` inhereted from GenericAPIView,so modelViewSet requires `queryset` and `serializer_class` attributes set in ModelViewSet.

3.*get_objects() method can we override in (viewsets.ViewSet) class? or get_objects() method only limited to (viewsets.ModelViewSet) class?.*

```
**get_object** and **get_queryset** belongs to **GenericViewSet(GenericAPIView)** class, in ModelViewSet this GenericViewSet inherited by default so it works only in **ModelViewSet** and **get_object** method no use in ViewSet.
```

for more info check this [article](https://www.vtuallinoneresources.com/latest-blog/19/django-rest-view-hierarchy-in-detail), next time you wont ask an question

Comment: so, we don't need to use `ViewSet` because `ModelViewSet` inherits the whole attributes and methods from `ViewSet` and `GenericAPIView` ?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer and just wanted to add some more points to it.
The ModelViewset is similar to standard Viewset but it is made to manage model and have several built in functionality.Also we can override the default object manager functions like create, update ,etc as per our need.So yes ModelViewset is made to manage database objects for a model.